# Apache Jmeter giving 404 error

Tags: java, jmeter

I am using Jmeter to load test my application. I am running proxy and recording urls and than logging out from system, but when i am running load test it is giving error

> Response code: 400
>  Response message: Bad Request

. I wanted to know what data is transferred to server when i access application from browser so that i can compare and check the difference and correct it? I am using *HHTP request Default* to capture request response is this correct option to choose

Recorded urls

```
/webdynpro/dispatcher/mycomp.com/call_agent_dtop-login_wd/COPSApp
/webdynpro/dispatcher/mycomp.com/call_agent_dtop-login_wd/j_security_check
/webdynpro/dispatcher/mycomp.com/call_agent_dtop-login_wd/COPSApp
/com.sap.ui.lightspeed/js/html/browserhistory.html
/webdynpro/dispatcher/mycomp.com/call_agent_dtop-login_wd/COPSApp
/webdynpro/dispatcher/mycomp.com/call_agent_dtop-login_wd/COPSApp
```

The error is coming when jmeter hetting last two urls.
Following are request and response.
**REQUEST**

> POST
>   `http://mysapserver:50000/webdynpro/dispatcher/mycomp.com/call_agent_dtop-login_wd/COPSApp`
>
> POST data:
>   sap-wd-appwndid=fa028617c40811e1b5040000008d9afa&sap-wd-cltwndid=fa028616c40811e1ca090000008d9afa&sap-wd-norefresh=X&sap-wd-secure-id=kr5Ff681H2UwyCLAfl7u0w%3D%3D&SAPEVENTQUEUE=ComboBox_Select%EE%80%82Id%EE%80%84PEJNDIPG.OrderView.ChangeDeliveryPlantDropDown%EE%80%85Key%EE%80%8411%EE%80%83%EE%80%82%EE%80%83%EE%80%82urEventName%EE%80%84COMBOBOXSELECTIONCHANGE%EE%80%83%EE%80%81InputField_Change%EE%80%82Id%EE%80%84PEJNDIPG.OrderView.ProductCodeInputField.0%EE%80%85Value%EE%80%840001%EE%80%83%EE%80%82Delay%EE%80%84full%EE%80%83%EE%80%82ContextPath%EE%80%84OrderTakingNode.0%EE%80%85urEventName%EE%80%84INPUTFIELDCHANGE%EE%80%83%EE%80%81InputField_Change%EE%80%82Id%EE%80%84PEJNDIPG.OrderView.ShadeCodeInputField.0%EE%80%85Value%EE%80%840123%EE%80%83%EE%80%82Delay%EE%80%84full%EE%80%83%EE%80%82ContextPath%EE%80%84OrderTakingNode.0%EE%80%85urEventName%EE%80%84INPUTFIELDCHANGE%EE%80%83%EE%80%81InputField_Enter%EE%80%82Id%EE%80%84PEJNDIPG.OrderView.ShadeCodeInputField.0%EE%80%83%EE%80%82ClientAction%EE%80%84submit%EE%80%83%EE%80%82ContextPath%EE%80%84OrderTakingNode.0%EE%80%85urEventName%EE%80%84INPUTFIELDKEYPRESS%EE%80%83%EE%80%81Form_Request%EE%80%82Id%EE%80%84...form%EE%80%85Async%EE%80%84false%EE%80%85FocusInfo%EE%80%84%40%7B%22iCursorPosX%22%3A+4%2C+%22iSelectionStart%22%3A+-1%2C+%22iSelectionEnd%22%3A+-1%2C+%22bNavigation%22%3A+true%2C+%22sFocussedId%22%3A+%22PEJNDIPG.OrderView.ShadeCodeInputField.0%22%2C+%22sApplyControlId%22%3A+%22PEJNDIPG.OrderView.ShadeCodeInputField.0%22%7D%EE%80%85Hash%EE%80%84%EE%80%85DomChanged%EE%80%84false%EE%80%85IsDirty%EE%80%84false%EE%80%83%EE%80%82EnqueueCardinality%EE%80%84single%EE%80%83%EE%80%82%EE%80%83
>
> Cookie Data: saplb_*=(J2EE9280220)9280250;
>   MYSAPSSO2=AjExMDAgABRwb3J0YWw6QWRtaW5pc3RyYXRvcogAB2RlZmF1bHQBAAACAAMwMDADAANDMkQEAAwyMDEyMDcwMjA1NDgFAAQAAAAICgAA%2FwEEMIIBAAYJKoZIhvcNAQcCoIHyMIHvAgEBMQswCQYFKw4DAhoFADALBgkqhkiG9w0BBwExgc8wgcwCAQEwIjAdMQwwCgYDVQQDEwNDMkQxDTALBgNVBAsTBEoyRUUCAQAwCQYFKw4DAhoFAKBdMBgGCSqGSIb3DQEJAzELBgkqhkiG9w0BBwEwHAYJKoZIhvcNAQkFMQ8XDTEyMDcwMjA1NDgzN1owIwYJKoZIhvcNAQkEMRYEFNDGciHoepD4FlNvbHBk2SqJFUspMAkGByqGSM44BAMELjAsAhQTb!2niESxzk4e3IXYrKWIhwUtjAIUZ1%2FFxpnUNIOwzFAXTo0rAtH!fms%3D;
>   JSESSIONID=UihOx6IlLj4iAkSoNex-4dhBwjtGOAH6mo0A_SAP-3GDWGtiIZOq-At49VanSwh-;
>   JSESSIONMARKID=MqO5Rwx41AYICm0wFgHl13dXEIdMBZcQ_00PqajQA
>
> Request Headers: Accept-Language: en-in Content-Length: 1660
>   Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate Referer:
>   `http://mysapserver:50000/webdynpro/dispatcher/mycomp.com/call_agent_dtop-login_wd/COPSApp?DealerCode=0000185994&CallId=0000123456`
>   User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1;
>   Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR
>   3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0) Connection: keep-alive Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded Accept: */* Pragma: no-cache

**RESPONSE**

> Thread Name: COPS-Thread-Group 1-1 Sample Start: 2012-07-02 11:11:43
>   IST Load time: 11 Latency: 10 Size in bytes: 26581 Headers size in
>   bytes: 231 Body size in bytes: 26350 Sample Count: 1 Error Count: 1
>   Response code: 400 Response message: Bad Request
>
> Response headers: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request server: SAP NetWeaver
>   Application Server 7.20 / AS Java 7.30 cache-control: no-cache,
>   no-store expires: -1 pragma: no-cache, no-store date: Mon, 02 Jul 2012
>   05:48:44 GMT transfer-encoding: chunked
>
> HTTPSampleResult fields: ContentType:  DataEncoding: null

If you need more information please tell me.
**Thanks a lot**

Comment: Actually it gives a `400 Bad Request` error which is completely different to a `404 Not Found` error

Comment: You've looked in your server's access and error logs, right?  What did you find there?

Answer (score 0):

The `400 Bad Request` error is an HTTP status code that probably you sent a malformed request to the server and the server was unable to understand or process the request.

Comment: I recorded the url through jmeter proxy and than running the test. I did not changed anything not even cookie or header . After recording i am running test directly.Do i need to change some data? or i need to set cookie? ot sth else. Myapp requires login without that youcan not access any other pages.

Comment: From my experience the JMeter proxy isn't very reliable (haven't used it in ages so may have improved). I would, instead use a different http sniffing tool (eg. Fiddler) and then build my requests for JMeter manually. Chances are the Proxy missed something.

Comment: I am not able to fix out yet. can you please provide any good tutorial link